# User defined modules storage

Tags: python, python-module

I am pretty much new to Python and cannot quite understand the scenario below.

Firstly, there exists no module so the error below is understandable.

```
>>> import module1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import module1
ImportError: No module named module1
```

Then I created the module and the sentences below worked perfectly.

**module1.py**

```
def func():
    print 'this is a test module'
```

**Python IDLE**

```
>>> import module1
>>> module1.func()
this is a test module
```

On the execution of the first statement, `module1.pyc` file was created. Then I added another function to module1.py.

**module1.py**

```
def func():
    print 'this is a test module'

def func1():
    print 'this is func1'
```

and tried to import this new file and run the statements below. But error was thrown as follows.

**Python IDLE**

```
>>> import module1
>>> module1.func1()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    module1.func1()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'func1'
```

I then deleted `module1.py` from the folder and then re-saved `module1.py` (with no contents changed). Again I executed the above statements in the IDLE prompt and the same error was thrown. And this time when the `import module1` statement was executed, `module1.pyc` file wasn't created unlike the previous time.

However, on restarting the IDLE everything works perfectly but why doesn't the IDE recompile the `module1.pyc` everytime import statement is executed(without restarting or opening another IDLE window) or could anyone explain what exactly happens in the memory when `import` statement is executed everytime.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import a module that has already been imported, it will not "re-import" and you will just get a reference to the original module.

You should use [`reload`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) to re-import the module if it has been already imported:

```
reload(module1)
```